# How can I use a special char in a C# enum?

Tags: .net, enums, special-characters

For example:

```
public enum Unit{
  KW,
  kV,
  V,
  Hz,
  %V
}
```

In this case % is a special character. So, how can I put this char in a enum?

Comment: Short and Long answer: You can't...

Comment: I'm not sure why you are after special characters in your enum, however if you are like me and you need to display a better name than perhaps type using the XmlEnumAttribute values for an Enum Check out my blog for more details [http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/post/2010/01/08/How-do-you-retrieving-the-XmlEnumAttribute-values-for-an-Enum.aspx](http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/post/2010/01/08/How-do-you-retrieving-the-XmlEnumAttribute-values-for-an-Enum.aspx)

Comment: Even if you can (based on a possible answer below), it is really, really bad practice, because every time you try to use it, it's going to muddy up the code readability.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enum members shouldn't be used for user interface display purposes. They should be mapped to a string in order to get displayed. You can create a string array (or a dictionary) that maps each enum member to a string for user interaction.

<strike>That said, to answer your question directly, you can use `\uxxxxV` were `xxxx` is the hexadecimal number representing the Unicode code point for `%`. This is far from recommended.</strike> As Henk points out, this won't work for `%` as it's not in Unicode classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, Nl, Mn, Mc, Nd, Pc, Cf (letters, digits, connecting, and formatting characters). Only these characters are acceptable for identifiers.

Comment: if \\xxx is not accepted as an alpha char (and % isn't) this still gives a compile error. % = \0025

Comment: Content where content belongs. Better to associate the strings with the enum members using an attibute then using a separate string array.

Comment: @AMissico: It's not always practical to do that. For example, when you have `[Flags]`  enums, there won't be one to one relationship between values of an enum types to enum members.

Comment: @Mehrdad, true, but usually flag enums are not represented to the user as strings.

Comment: @AMissico: I can see of some cases where they are. Anyway, another reason I prefer an imperative mapping (rather than a declarative one, which is useful in plenty of cases) is that going back from the string representation to the enum value is much easier.

Comment: @Mehrdad, we are in agreement. I like to stick with the attributes to be consistent. This allows me to follow the "content" rule, which helps with code review and maintainence. I have a method that takes a string value and does a "lookup" based on specified attribute to return the "closest" or "exact" enum member.

Comment: +1 This is the only way to go, particularly if you're planning to localize your application.

Comment: I agree. Instead of a dictionary you can also decorate those enums with custom attributes : `[MyCustomAttribute("some string")]`

Answer (score 36):

Even if you could do that (and it looks you can't), it probably wouldn't be a good idea, because you'd be mixing how the enum should be displayed with the program code to manipulate it. A better option would be to define an attribute (or use existing `DisplayNameAttribute`) and annotate your enum with names as additional meta-data:

```
public enum Unit{ 
  [DisplayName("Hz")] Hertz, 
  [DisplayName("%V")] Volt 
}
```

Comment: +1 on this approach. We use a DisplayKeyAttribute which correlates an enum value with a localizable string.

Comment: I used the Description attribute instead since I received this error when using DisplayName: "Attribute 'DisplayName' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, method, property, indexer, event' declarations."

Answer (score 7):

Just to register another way to do that, in a simple way, you can define "your own" enumerator with constants. In your example

```
public class UnitEnum
{
  public const string KW = "KW";
  public const string Volt = "%V";
}
```

To access, it just: `UnitEnum.Volt`

Answer (score 4):

This answer is related to the one from @Coppermill I feel using the DescriptionAttribute is more semantically correct when working with Enums

```
public enum ReportStatus
{
    [Description("Reports that are running")] Running,
    [Description("Reports that are pending to run")] Pending,
    [Description("Reports that have errored while running")] Error,
    [Description("Report completed successfully.")] Finished
}
```

Then I read from it like such

```
    public static bool IsNullable(this Type type)
    {
        if (!type.IsGenericType)
            return false;
        var g = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        return (g.Equals(typeof (Nullable<>)));
    }

    public static Type ConcreteType(this Type type)
    {
        if (IsNullable(type))
            type = UnderlyingTypeOf(type);
        return type;
    }
```

.

```
    public static string ReadDescription<T>(T enumMember)
    {
        if (typeof (T).IsNullable() && enumMember == null) return null;

        var type = (typeof (T).ConcreteType());

        var fi = type.GetField(enumMember.ToString());

        var attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if(attributes.Length == 0) return enumMember.ToString();

        return attributes.Cast<DescriptionAttribute>().First().Description;
    }
```

Then usage would be `ReadDescription(ReportStatus.Running)` I also have a method that will convert an Enum into a KeyValuePair Enumerable for binding an Enum to a DropDown.

Comment: As a follow up to this many years later. I've stopped using enums unless i actually intended to use `[Flags]`. At this point I use static classes and strong types instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19324419/37055

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I just realized that I didn't answer the question. I will not delete my answer because someone may find these code snippets helpful.

---

I agree completely with Tomas Petricek, so I will not repeat his answer.

Here is my solution to the problem. I been using this code for about five years. I decided to create a custom attribute in order to use the DisplayName attribute for captions and such.

---

```
Public Module MainModule
    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(EnumEx.GetNumberFormatString(Unit.Volt), 120.13)
    End Sub
End Module
```

---

```
Public Enum Unit
    <NumberFormatString("{0} Hz"), DisplayName("Hertz")> Hz
    <NumberFormatString("{0} %V"), DisplayName("%Volt")> pV
End Enum
```

---

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)> _
Public NotInheritable Class NumberFormatStringAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Public Shared ReadOnly [Default] As NumberFormatStringAttribute = New NumberFormatStringAttribute

    Private _format As String

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(Char.MinValue)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal format As String)
        _format = format
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
        If (obj Is Me) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Dim oAttribute As NumberFormatStringAttribute = TryCast(obj, NumberFormatStringAttribute)
        If (Not oAttribute Is Nothing) Then
            Return (oAttribute.NumberFormatString = Me.NumberFormatString)
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return Me.NumberFormatString.GetHashCode
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function IsDefaultAttribute() As Boolean
        Return Me.Equals(NumberFormatStringAttribute.Default)
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property NumberFormatString() As String
        Get
            Return Me.NumberFormatStringValue
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Property NumberFormatStringValue() As String
        Get
            Return _format
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _format = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

---

```
Public NotInheritable Class EnumEx

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetNumberFormatString(ByVal value As Object) As String
        Dim sResult As String = Nothing
        Dim oFieldInfo As System.Reflection.FieldInfo = value.GetType.GetField(value.ToString)
        If Not (oFieldInfo Is Nothing) Then
            Dim oCustomAttributes() As Object = oFieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(NumberFormatStringAttribute), True)
            If (Not (oCustomAttributes Is Nothing)) AndAlso oCustomAttributes.Length > 0 Then
                sResult = DirectCast(oCustomAttributes(0), NumberFormatStringAttribute).NumberFormatString
            End If
        End If
        Return sResult
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum members shouldn't be used for user interface display purposes. But you can use **simple tricks** with **DisplayName("Your Property Display Name")** for this matter as bellow.

```
//Enum
public enum ErrorCodes
{
      [DisplayName("U-volt")] UVolt = 2,
      [DisplayName("L-trip")] Ltrip = 5
}


//Here you can retrive Display name as bellow
public class MyClass{
     public void readEnumDisplayName(){
         String ErroCode = Enum.GetName(typeof(ErrorCodes), 5);    // Find Error Name using Integer value
          MemberInfo property = typeof(ErrorCodes).GetRuntimeField(ErroCode);     //Find Field
          var dd = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute;   //Find Display Attribute
          if (dd != null)  //Check if null
          {
             var name = dd.DisplayName;   //Retrive Display name
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Some can state that Enumerations are for Code only, I must disagree and I use to Code and Display functionality.

In your particular case I would use the full word

```
public enum UnitType {
  Kilowatt,
  Kilovolt,
  Volt,
  Hertz,
  Ohm,
  Faraday
}
```

So I can use them in a Dropdown for example as (when I need to create a new item, all I need to do is append that item into the Enumeration...

```
ddl.Items.Clear();
foreach (string type in Enum.GetNames(typeof(UnitType)))
    ddl.Items.Add(type);
```

I tend to use Space Separator, but I normally use underscore to make spaces, like

```
public enum myType { Process_Time, Process_Order, Process_Invoices }
```

and the DropDownList item would be

```
ddl.Items.Add(type.Replace("_", " "));
```

when I want to set the Type from the DropDown, I use the Parse

```
UnitType unit = (UnitType)Enum.Parse(
                                 typeof(UnitType),
                                 ddl.SelectedValue.toString());
```

off course, if you use Separator

```
 ddl.SelectedValue.toString().Replace(" ", "_"));
```

**Some rules** to have in consideration to write better code

- Always write **Type** to an Enum, in you case Unit should be **UnitType**
- Use Title Case for Enumeration Objects

**As a reminder**

- You can use an Enum in a Bit Operation adding [Flags] keyword
- You can specify the integer value of the Enum if you don't want to have: 0, 1, 2, 3...

I hope I can help someone.

Comment: Down voted because you are hard-coding your actual code for presentation purposes.

Comment: You should bin any refactoring book that recommends you do this. 
Your code is brittle and hard to refactor because changing the enum causes your UI to break - and I doubt you have integration tests at that level so it'll probably go live.