# Access "this" inside of static codeblocks

Tags: c#, static, grammar

Lately I've found myself writing alot of classes similar to:

```
public class MyTypeCodes
{
    public static MyTypeCode E = new MyTypeCode{ Desc= "EEE", Value = "E" };
    public static MyTypeCode I = new MyTypeCode { Desc= "III", Value = "I" };

    private static readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<MyTypeCode>> AllMyTypeCodes =
        new Lazy<IEnumerable<MyTypeCode>>(() =>
        {
            var typeCodes = typeof(MyTypeCodes)
                 .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                 .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof (MyTypeCode))
                 .Select(x => (MyTypeCode) x.GetValue(null))
                 .ToList();

                 return typeCodes;
        });

    public static IEnumerable<MyTypeCode> All
    {
        get { return AllMyTypeCodes.Value; }
    }
}
```

If you notice inside of  `new Lazy<IEnumerable<MyTypeCode>>(() =>` that I specifically need to do `typeof(MyTypeCodes)` even though I'm inside of class MyTypeCodes. Is there any way I can write this without specifically need to call `typeof()` for the class i'm specifically inside of? If this was a regular method I would `this.GetType()` which obviously doesn't work (for some reason) with statics.

Comment: FYI - You should use `ToList()` on the `IEnumerable` sequence here... Otherwise, every call will run through reflection again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way I can write this without specifically need to call typeof() for the class i'm specifically inside of?

No, this is likely the best option.  If you know you are never going to add any other fields, of any other types, you can just skip the `Where` clause.

In addition, you should use `ToList()` to prevent the `IEnumerable<T>` generated from having to rerun each time it's enumerated:

```
private static readonly Lazy<IEnumerable<MyTypeCode>> AllMyTypeCodes =
    new Lazy<IEnumerable<MyTypeCode>>(() =>
    {
        return typeof(MyTypeCodes)
             .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
             // If you're not using any other fields, just skip this
             // .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof (MyTypeCode ))
             .Select(x => (MyTypeCode) x.GetValue(null))
             .ToList();                 
    });
```

Comment: @ChrisMarisic `this` refers to an instance in C#.  There would have to be some other keyword for this, but there just isn't in the language...

Comment: I understand that, i just disagree with it. This inside a static scope should refer to this instance, which perchance is static.

Answer (score 0):

Make a private constructor that gives you a (privately held) reference.

```
private MyTypeCodes() { }
private static MyTypeCodes _instance = new MyTypeCodes();

public static DoSomethingWithType()
{
  return _instance.GetType().foo();
}
```

Or you could have the constructor call GetType() and just use that instead of calling _instance.GetType() every time you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the semantics, you could do:

```
private static readonly Type _thisType = typeof(MyTypeCodes);

// use like
var typeCodes = _thisType.GetFields(...
```