# Which are the accepted special characters that can be used in an Enum?

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax, enums, character

This is the scenario:

I'm using a 3rd party SDK dll, I should pass a `PREDEFINED` string argument to almost all the dll methods, and exist more than 800 predefined possible strings to pass to the method, the documentation is very poor and the examples are obsolete, the dll in question is `MediaInfoLib`, the strings are case sensitive so this has the risk that easylly an error can occur (anybody can remember the syntax of all those 800 strings...) so I want to put all the possible vlaues in an Enumeration to call the method like this:

```
sub method(byval param as myEnum)

  call API method(param.tostring)

End sub
```

Then that way any error can occur because the right stringcase syntax is specified by me in the enum, and also has the advantage of I don't need to remember the syntax of the 800 strings, I can pick the desired value from the Enum.

Well, the problem is that some strings are named like this:

```
StreamKind/String
CodecID/Url
```

...I can't put the / char in the Enum.

Of course I thinked about replacing the "/" char for a "_" char, but I can't do this because exists some other strings names as this:

```
CodecID_Description
Width_Offset
```

So If I replace those chars I would get a false positive.

Then what can I do with this?

I Can't find any special character that can be used in a Enum because it takes in conflick with the VB operators...

I would like to know if exist a list of accepted/forbidden characters for an enum, or if someone knows a good special character that I can use instead of "/" char?, for special character I mean anyone but not from alphabet like these: ÑñÇç, because I'm searching an accepted character that looks a separator.

or any other idea?

Comment: duplicate of [How can I use a special char in a C# enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373986/how-can-i-use-a-special-char-in-a-c-sharp-enum)

Comment: @Haji, this is a VBNET question.

Comment: Why does it have to be an enum? Why not just have a module with string constants? (and using plainer/consistent naming)

Comment: @ElektroStudios . in both c# and vb.net the concept won't change mostly. syntax only differ.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I preffer the Enum because the Intellisense shows all the values when picking the enum then you know the range of possible values, using constants I still need to remember the name of one of those 800 constants to write it correctly, also some strings has identical names but are used for different methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something you might want to consider given your approach (this would not fit in a comment).  Your Enum Maker sorts the params, and it sounds like you plan the use the Enum name as the param request to MediaInfo (item 1 in your post).  If you add fake MaxGeneral, MaxAudio and MaxVideo entries, you can easily determine which streamKind parameter to use.

```
MediaInfoParms
   Filename
   fileSize
   '...
   EPG_Positions_End    ' i think this is the last General one
   MAX_GENERAL = EPG_Positions_End    

  ' long list of Video enums
  BufferSize              ' last Video I think
  MAX_VIDEO = BufferSize
  ....
```

Now when you go to call MediaInfo:

```
 Select Case thisEnumVal 
     Case Is =< MediaInfoParms.MAX_GENERAL
        streamKind = MediaInfo.streamGeneral

     Case Is =< MediaInfoParms.MAX_AUDIO
         streamKind = MediaInfo.streamAudio
     '...
```

`Info_Parameters` already serves them up grouped, your EnumMaker just needs to look for "General", "Audio" and "Video" as the only text in a line to know where each groups starts (your EnamMaker is also currently including these Titles as enum values, too).

Or, your EnumMaker could just track the end of each group and add constant definitions after the `End Enum`:

```
 Public Const Max_MediaInfo_General = 278  '(whatever value)
 Public Const Max_MediaInfo_Video = 482
```

If the enum is meant to be a 'library' and you actually use a subset of the ones actually needed in apps (many of them are just there because it is defined somewhere in some obscure standard as a legal tag), then have EnumMaker add values (`BufferSize = 482`) and use Const definitions so they stay in synch in the subset.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

I use MediaInfo.DLL (a LOT) and know what you are talking about.  First, you can capture all the arguments and what they return thru one of the Info methods and save to a text file such as:

```
Info_Parameters           (this is the mediaInfo key to use to tell it 
                          to dump all the params it knows)
General 
Count                     : Number of objects available in this stream
Status       : bit field (0=IsAccepted, 1=IsFilled, 2=IsUpdated,   3=IsFinished)
StreamCount               : Number of streams of this kind available
StreamKind                : Stream type name
```

The obvious answer is that you are trying to use an Enum as a class almost: that is rather than just a meaningful identifier in code, you also want to use the name as a parameter elsewhere.  Been there, done that.  I handled that this way (this wont exactly answer your question because you already have an answer in mind):

```
Friend Enum MediaInfoItem As Integer
    <Description("File name"), MIKey("FileName"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.File), MIDtl(True)> FileName
    <Description("File Size"), MIKey("FileSize"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.File), MIDtl(True), MIFmt(True)> FileSize
    <Description("Duration"), MIKey("Duration"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.File), MIDtl(True), MIFmt(True)> Duration
    <Description("Format Profile"), MIKey("Format_Profile"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.File), MILvl(PropLvl.XTD)> FormatProfile

    ' mp3 type stuff are in the general, not audio stream
    <Description("Album"), MIKey("Album"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.File), MILvl(PropLvl.DLG)> Album
    <Description("Artist"), MIKey("Artist"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.File), MILvl(PropLvl.DLG)> Artist
    '...
    <Description("Audio Format"), MIKey("Format"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.Audio), MIDtl(True)> AudioFormat
    <Description("Format Info"), MIKey("Format/Info"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.Audio)> AudioFormatInfo
    <Description("Format Profile"), MIKey("Format_Profile"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.Audio), MILvl(PropLvl.XTD)> AudioFormatProfile
    <Description("Codec"), MIKey("Codec/String"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.Audio), MIDtl(True)> AudioCodec

    <Description("Video Format"), MIKey("Format"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.Video), MIDtl(True)> VideoFormat
    <Description("Video Format Info"), MIKey("Format/Info"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.Video)> VideoFormatInfo
    <Description("Format Profile"), MIKey("Format_Profile"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.Video), MILvl(PropLvl.XTD)> VideoFormatProfile
    <Description("Codec"), MIKey("Codec/String"), MIGrp(MediaInfoGroup.Video)> VideoCodec
    ...
```

There are more than 50 that I use in this.  One issue that you may not have, but I do is that many parameters are the same: Codec is the same for Audio as Video ("Codec/String") and it is the stream argument that varies making 'Codec' invalid for the Enum name.  Because so many params are the same, the Enum makes a nice way to glue them to the right param and associate it with a unique identifier.

I make use of custom attributes to separate, categorize and track the params for each entry:

- Description is the text to use in the output/UI (I dont think this is much different than the DisplayName attribute from one of the comment links at least as far as getting it, but I am going to look at that.)
- MIKey is the MediaInfo.DLL key to use to get this info
- MIGrp tells which stream to poll in MediaInfo (file, audio, video) and controls which group to use when this is displayed in a ListView (I also have a "virtual" group which I wont go into)
- MIDtl and MILvl are indicators for the apps that use this
- MIFmt determines whether the return from MediaInfo needs to be formatted to be useful

If the attributes you define incorporate a default return value, you can skip decorations where the value is the default (my MILvl defaults to "Standard" for instance), and you can then create a List(of MediaInfoItem) in a loop:

```
Private Sub BuildPropList()
    Dim vals As MediaInfoItem() = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(MediaInfoItem))
    Dim mi As MIProp

    For Each n As MediaInfoItem In vals
        mi = New MIProp(n)       ' magic happens here
        _props.Add(mi)
    Next
End Sub
```

Polling MediaInfo for the info becomes a mere matter of walking thru the propsList and feeding MediaInfo the params stored: stream to poll is MIGrp, the property key is from MIKey which might be all you need (my implementation also stores the output, formats it and so forth).  To add new items as you are developing, it is just a matter of adding a new Enum item.  (I use a List(of T) so that the order is preserved and to avoid a DisplayOrder attribute (see link below), you'd probably want a Dictionary to fetch various MediaInfo properties via the Enum value.)

I have 3 apps that use this, one of which is an [Explorer shell extension](http://i41.tinypic.com/2093tzm.png).  There is no code required aside from the MediaInfoitem List except to post the data to a ListView for display (another use for MIGrp, and just another loop).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really the solution is nice but the inconvenient is that way I could need years for writting all the values, it's a pitty, but good solution of course. like most parameters are duplicated and means the same then I really preffer to put them all in a unique Enum (not separate them by video, audio, general, etc...). If you use MediaInfo a lot like you've said then maybe you could be interested in some code of my answer, take a look :).

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my solution, this code retrieves the MediaInfo Parametters as CSV list and filters the list to write the Enum members and their summary documentation.

**Some things to clarify:**

1. The parametters are joined and sortered, so them won't match with the mediainfo.dll `GetInfoI` method (which needs an Integer), by the way this Enum can be used perfectly with the `GetInfo` method which expects a String, the intention is to avoid the usage of the `GetInfoI` because with this Enum I think that the `GetInfoI` method beings obsolete and not usefull.
2. The generated Enum has about 3.000 lines, it needs to manually remove some duplicates, just around 20 duplicates, it just takes five mins to remove them.
3. The `/` character is replaced by an `__`, So I've rewritten the original MediaInfo VBNET SDK Example and this is how my method looks:

   ```
   ''' <summary>
   ''' Gets a piece of information about a file.
   ''' </summary>
   ''' <param name="StreamKind">
   ''' Kind of stream (general, video, audio...).
   ''' </param>
   ''' <param name="StreamNumber">
   ''' Stream number in this kind of stream (first, second...).
   ''' </param>
   ''' <param name="Info">
   ''' The information to retrieve.
   ''' </param>
   ''' <param name="KindOfInfo">
   ''' Kind of information you want about the parameter (the text, the measure, the help...). 
   ''' </param>
   ''' <param name="KindOfSearch">
   ''' Where to look for the parameter . 
   ''' </param>
   Public Function GetInfo(ByVal StreamKind As StreamKind,
                           ByVal StreamNumber As Integer,
                           ByVal Info As MediaInfoOption,
                           Optional ByVal KindOfInfo As InfoKind = InfoKind.Text,
                           Optional ByVal KindOfSearch As InfoKind = InfoKind.Name) As String

   Return System.Runtime.InteropServices.
          Marshal.PtrToStringUni(SafeNativeMethods.
                                 MediaInfo_Get(Handle,
                                               New IntPtr(StreamKind),
                                               New IntPtr(StreamNumber),
                                               Info.ToString.Replace("_s_", "(s)").Replace("__", "/"),
                                               New IntPtr(KindOfInfo),
                                               New IntPtr(KindOfSearch)))

   End Function
   ```

Here is the code to generate the Enum:

```
Private Sub MakeMediaInfoEnum() Handles MyBase.Shown

    Dim TempFile As String = IO.Path.GetTempFileName
    Dim OutFile As String = "C:\MediaInfo Enum.vb"
    Dim ReplaceChar1 As String = "__" ' Replacement for "/" char.
    Dim ReplaceChar2 As String = "_s_" ' Replacement for "(s)" chars.
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

    IO.File.WriteAllText(TempFile,
                         New MediaInfo().LibraryInfo(MediaInfo.MediaInfoLibInfo.Info_Parameters_CSV),
                         System.Text.Encoding.Default)

    sb.AppendLine("Public Enum MediaInfoOption")
    sb.AppendLine("")

    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadLines(TempFile,
                                                 System.Text.Encoding.Default).
                                                 Where(Function(l) _
                                                       l.Contains(";") _
                                                       AndAlso Not l.ToLower.Contains("deprecated") _
                                                       AndAlso Not l.ToLower.StartsWith("default") _
                                                       AndAlso Not l.ToLower.StartsWith("forced") _
                                                       AndAlso Not l.ToLower.StartsWith("bits-(iixel*frame)")).
                                                 OrderBy(Function(l) l).
                                                 Distinct()

        sb.AppendLine("''' <summary>")

        sb.AppendLine("''' " & If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(";") + 1)),
                                  line.Substring(line.IndexOf(";") + 1),
                              "( UNDOCUMENTED PARAMETER )"))

        sb.AppendLine("''' </summary>")
        sb.AppendLine(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(";")).
                      Replace("/", ReplaceChar1).
                      Replace("(s)", ReplaceChar2))

        sb.AppendLine("")

    Next

    sb.AppendLine("End Enum")

    IO.File.WriteAllText(OutFile, sb.ToString, System.Text.Encoding.Default)

End Sub
```

The code above generates a textfile like this:

```
Public Enum MediaInfoOption

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Format used
    ''' </summary>
    Format

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Commercial name used by vendor for theses setings or Format field if there is no difference
    ''' </summary>
    Format_Commercial

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Commercial name used by vendor for theses setings if there is one
    ''' </summary>
    Format_Commercial_IfAny

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Compression method used
    ''' </summary>
    Format_Compression

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Profile of this Format
    ''' </summary>
    Format_Profile

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Settings needed for decoder used
    ''' </summary>
    Format_Settings

  etc...

End Enum
```

---

And here is my full rewritten version of the original `MediaInfo` vbnet class taken from the SDK (I hope that I modified the code in the right way but I'm not a guru).

I've added documentation, method overloads, enums, and some unusefull things (for me) are removed from the original code like non-implemented methods and the `menu` and `chapters` members ofthe `StreamKind` enum.

http://pastebin.com/XGUwW8hQ

Comment: Did you see the new Jan, 2014 version - it has a 32 and 64 bit version now.  I had a cool AnyCPU interface which is broke now.